# Python exe not working without console but with console, it's working

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I'm create a exe file with pyinstaller.I'm create with this command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile mybot.py
```

It's worked without showing any error. But I want without console so I'm used this command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w mybot.py
```

Now It's showing error on a popup: *failed to execute script mybot*

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Does you script write anything on the console (when it runs with it of course...)?

Answer (score 0):

Your script had module run on console like os,... You may need to replace those module to another windowed module to support windowed executable

EDIT: You can use subprocess.Popen instead of os

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. Can you explain, How to do that?

Comment: The wrong is one of your added library using console (command prompt) to working, this mean you need to use another library to work with windowed file

Comment: I'm not use `os`. I'm used `subprocess` But when I delete this line of code my exe file is work without showing error: `import subprocess
device_id = str(subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get uuid'), 'utf-8').split('\n')[1].strip()
print(device_id)` what can I do now?

Comment: You can remove print(device_id) and replace it with GUI interface, print uses in command promt

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem earlier. I was using PHPMyAdmin to store the database files. This is what worked for me. I stored the Database(sql) file in the same folder as the python file and changed the library I was using for accessing the sql file.
Then it worked perfectly for me. I think you need to make sure that all the files are in the same folder.

Comment: My all file in the same folder. But it's not working?